# Percentage sign missing in newsletter and in the blog post

Tags: bug, email, blog, newsletter, the-overflow

Today's newsletter contains this sentence:

> Research has found that almost 90 of machine learning models developed by companies never make it into production.

Just 90 out of all the models ever made? That's not that bad! ;)

Same with the [actual blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/10/23/the-overflow-44-machine-learning-in-production/):

[image: missing percentage in blog post]

Comment: I'm not so sure about those tags: This newsletter is not from 2011, but [tag:the-overflow] only has 2 questions. So which tag is correct?

Comment: It's the mail newsletter called "The overflow".

Comment: Re edit: I guess that text was separately typed from the post itself? In that case it might just be a typo. I just found it suspicious that a percentage sign is stripped out of something that gets sent in HTML format.